# Jquery mobile popup with loading spinner

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

The popup delays a long time to load in device.

How can I show a loading spinner before display a popup in jquery mobile?

This is a simplified version of my code:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="fixed_numbers">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Back</a>
        <h1>Header</h1>                  
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="dlg_fix" data-role="popup" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a"></div>
        <a href="#" id="fix_num_btn" data-value="test">Click Here!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#fixed_numbers", function() {

    $("#fixed_numbers").on("click", "#fix_num_btn", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // value receive a data from input hidden  
        var value = $(this).attr("data-value");
        $('#dlg_fix').html(value).popup('open');
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#fixed_numbers", function() {

    $("#fixed_numbers").on("click", "#fix_num_btn", function(e) {

        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

        e.preventDefault();
        // value receive a data from input hidden  
        var value = $(this).attr("data-value");
        $('#dlg_fix').html(value).popup('open');

    });
});
```

[see more page loading msg options from jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/config/loadingMessageTextVisible.html)

Comment: It's cool, but i would like to use the own spinner of jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#fixed_numbers").on("click", "#fix_num_btn", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); //Show  Sipnner
    var value = $(this).attr("data-value");
    $('#dlg_fix').html(value).popup('open');

});
```

Add a popupafteropen event listener, this will hide the spinner when the popup will be open.

```
$('#dlg_fix').on('popupafteropen', function (e) {
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zoharadar/RMbkF/5/)

for more popup events, check out JQM docs
[jqm docs - popup events](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/events.html)